# Ruby Selenium No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, capybara

Full dump below: Chrome will open and then just sit there. Newest version of chrome.

```
  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
  ./features/step_definitions/site_search_steps.rb:17:in `/^I go to my google page that I care about$/'
  features\site_search.feature:7:in `Given I go to my google page that I care about'
  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `raw_execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:257:in `getScreenshot'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:34:in `screenshot_as'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `block in save_screenshot'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `open'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver_extensions/takes_screenshot.rb:18:in `save_screenshot'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:78:in `save_screenshot'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:344:in `save_screenshot'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:51:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
  C:/Users/selahey/Source/Workspaces/Test Automation Code/websites_workspace/global_support/screenshot_methods.rb:19:in `take_screenshot'
  C:/Users/selahey/Source/Workspaces/Test Automation Code/websites_workspace/access_2_care_workspace/access_2_care_regression/features/support/env.rb:15:in `After'
  No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. - connect(2) (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `initialize'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `open'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `block in connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:763:in `connect'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1285:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:83:in `response_for'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:39:in `request'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:638:in `raw_execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:616:in `execute'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:365:in `deleteAllCookies'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.43.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/options.rb:67:in `delete_all_cookies'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:84:in `reset!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/session.rb:77:in `reset!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `block in reset_sessions!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `each'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara.rb:245:in `reset_sessions!'
  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/capybara-2.1.0/lib/capybara/cucumber.rb:10:in `After'
```

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber -p tags features\site_search.feature:6 # Scenario: Conduct a site search that should have results

1 scenario (1 failed)
1 step (1 failed)

Comment: I inherited this regression suite and am trying to find where it could be breaking. We have all of our versions locked with a gemfile.lock so I wonder if Chrome updated and broke our suite.

Comment: That would be my guess based on the error message.

Comment: Check your chrome version.  You may need a new version of `chromedriver.exe`: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: as @orde mentions - update to the latest version of chromedriver - should be 2.25 currently

Comment: I have the latest version and it does the same thing. I think a windows update actually broke it.